# MySqlWorkbench synchronization wizard does not apply selected schema

Tags: synchronization, mysql-workbench

I use MySql Workbench 6.3.10 on Windows 7 and try to synchronize a model with a database. I changed the database schema to `eload_basement` (selection of the combo box can only be changed after clicking on the single line in the table) but the synchronization is still done with the old schema `eload`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a **hidden button** `Override target` that needs to be pressed to apply the changes. In order to make that button visible, the width of the wizard window needs to be increased:

[image]

Also see related bug report:https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82306